# 'ERROR Invalid url' when trying to package / publish vscode extension

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to publish a new version of my vscode extension. I typed in `vsce package` and got `ERROR Invalid URL`. I then tried `vsce publish minor` and got

```
v1.1.0
ERROR Invalid URL
```

my package.json file:

```
"name": "google-dark",
  "displayName": "Google Dark",
  "description": "A dark, Google-colour inspired theme",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "icon": "./themes/images/icon.png",
  "publisher": "LWB",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/LeoWB/Google-Dark-VSCode-Theme"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "theme",
    "dark",
    "google",
    "colourful",
    "bright",
    "dark theme"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.77.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Themes"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "themes": [
      {
        "label": "Google Dark",
        "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
        "path": "./themes/Google Dark-color-theme.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The URL given for the repository does link to an actual page, so I don't know why it is giving me this error.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/739 (found by googling "`github vscode issues publish extension "ERROR Invalid URL"`"). What vsce version are you on? Is your vsce version greater than or equal to 2.9.3?

Comment: please add a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused because I was using a relative file path in my README.md file. I solved it by using the GitHub repo link to the image instead.